# Width of listview columns not respected

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, listview

I have a listview where I add several columns:

```
LVCOLUMN column;

column.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_SUBITEM | LVCF_IDEALWIDTH;
column.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;

for(size_t i = 0; i < columns.size(); ++i)
{
    const string columnName = Format("{0}. {1} ({2})", i + 1, columns[i].Name.empty() ? "?" : columns[i].Name, boost::to_lower_copy(columns[i].GetTypeName()));

    column.iSubItem = i;
    column.pszText = (char *)columnName.c_str();
    column.cchTextMax = columnName.length();
    column.cx = column.cxIdeal = (columns[i].Type == COLUMN_TYPE_STRING) ? 130 : 100;
    ListView_InsertColumn(mListView, i, &column);
    ++mColumnCount;
}
```

Notice in particular `column.cx = column.cxIdeal = (columns[i].Type == COLUMN_TYPE_STRING) ? 130 : 100;`.

This is not respected; this is how the listview looks like:

[image]

It's also worth mentioning that without targeting Windows Common Controls 6.0 in the manifest file the code works perfectly and the columns have the correct width.

**EDIT**: Setting cxMin to the width works, but then I can't manually resize the columns so that they have less width (at runtime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vista and up has auto-sizing for columns for version 6.  Its exact behavior isn't documented well.  Either drop LVCF_IDEALWIDTH or use LVCF_MINWIDTH and set the cxMin member.

Comment: I initially only had `LVCF_WIDTH` for the width related fields.. I added all the others only to try to make it work, but with only `LVCF_WIDTH` it doesn't. May it be related to the fact that the listview is in virtual mode (LVS_OWNERDATA)?

Comment: Unlikely, odd problem.  If you use LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE (ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle) at all then document what you pass.

Comment: I had `LVS_EX_AUTOSIZECOLUMNS` in there.. I added it because it seemed like a good idea but then completely forgot about it. Removed it now and my width is respected, thank you very much =)